# How can i add a sub Tag to an Xml file already defined using Java?

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have an XML file that contains the configration of a Spring project and I want to dynamically add a new bean. I have to modify the initial xML file and add my new bean definition:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="config"
        class="myclass">
        <property name="configXml">
            <value>config.xml</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

<-- here a want to add a new bean definition <bean>....</bean> -->

</beans>
```

Has anyone got an idea?

Comment: Dynamically? Do you mean at runtime?

Comment: yes , at runtime , the user dont need to define the bean he just give the relative information and the app generates the configuration file (XML) so to do that i have to add to the configuration file the new bean definition <bean>...</bean> wich have to be ander the tag <beans>

Comment: Doesn't sound like something you should be doing with Spring. What is in the new bean that you want to add?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not 100% what you mean, but here's two cases to try.

If you want to specify properties of a bean based on some derived value you can use the Spring Expression Language

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html

```
<bean id="someBean" class="example.SomeBean">
    <property name="foo" value="#{config.whatever}"/>
</bean>
```

If you want to something more complex you can construct a bean programatically using a factory bean

```
<bean id="someBean" class="example.SomeBeanFactory">
    <property name="config" ref="config"/>
</bean>
```

with something like

```
class SomeBeanFactory implements FactoryBean<SomeBean> {
    public void setConfig(MyClass config) { ... }

    public SomeBean getObject() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to modify the xml Spring configration file  by adding the new bean definition. In my case the configration file isn't a part of my Eclipse project , it is an external file because my beans are introduced to the app as jar file , i mean that the beans are also external . I dont want the user to make the definition of the bean , he just need to give me some information . The app add the bean definition for him .I used beanss.appendChild(bean); but there are no modifications to on the xml . I hope that i explained what i mean :)